# AES decrypt with key and IV (Cryptojs and C# involved)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I have an ASP.NET Core application that provides some data routes to be consumed by a SPA application (no UI framework(s) involved, just JavaScript and HTML5). Some values within the response JSON are encrypted using AES; the client needs to decrypt the values in order to display theme to the user. On the client side, I use CryptoJS, but I can´t get the decryption working. As follows, that´s what I´ve tried...

First, this is the function (server side code) that is used to encrypt the data using AES. It hashes a key and pin using SHA256 and uses the computed values for key and IV:

```cs
async Task<byte[]> Encrypt(string key, string pin, byte[] data)
{
    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        byte[] keyData = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{key}"));
        byte[] rgbIv = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{pin}"));
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            byte[] rgbKey = keyData.Slice(0, aes.Key.Length); // 32
            byte[] iv = rgbIv.Slice(0, aes.IV.Length); // 16
            using (ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, iv))
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var cryptStream = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                await cryptStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                await cryptStream.FlushAsync();

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Encrypted data is stored as Base64-encoded strings in the model, for instance:

```cs
class Model 
{
    public string EncryptedValue { get; set; }
}

...

byte[] data = Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes("...");
byte[] encrypted = await Encrypt("api-key", "123456", data);
var model = new Model { EncryptedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted) };
```

I installed crypto-js 3.1.12 using Bower:

```
bower install crypto-js
```

I picked required JavaScript files from the CryptoJS build folder; this is my bundle configuration I use to bundle all files (using `bundleconfig.json`; a working order of the files has been found by trial and error):

```
{
    "outputFileName": "Content/js/encryption.js",
    "minify": { "enabled": false },
    "inputFiles": [
        "bower_components/crypto-js/build/components/core.js",
        "bower_components/crypto-js/build/rollups/sha256.js",
        "bower_components/crypto-js/build/rollups/aes.js",
        "bower_components/crypto-js/build/components/cipher-core.js",
        "bower_components/crypto-js/build/components/enc-base64.js"
    ]
}
```

Since I implement all client side functionality in TypeScript, I also use the following TypeScript definition for crypto-js to get Intellisense in Visual Studio:

```
typings install dt~cryptojs --global
```

This is my client side code:

```js
import WordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray;

...

decodeData(data: string): JQueryPromise<string> {

    let deferred: JQueryDeferred<string> = $.Deferred<string>();

    this.obtainPublicKey().done((publicKey: string) => {

        this.promptUserPinCode().done((pin: string) => {

            let cipherBuffer: WordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data);

            let publicKeyHash: WordArray = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(publicKey));
            let key: WordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(publicKeyHash.words.slice(0, 8), 32);

            let pinHash: WordArray = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pin));
            let iv: WordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(pinHash.words.slice(0, 4), 16);

            let cfg: CryptoJS.lib.IBlockCipherCfg = {
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
                iv: iv
            };

            let params: CryptoJS.lib.CipherParamsData = {
                ciphertext: cipherBuffer,
                key: key,
                iv: iv,
                algorithm: CryptoJS.algo.AES,
                blockSize: 128,
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
                salt: CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([], 0)
            };

            let decrypted: WordArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(params, key, cfg);

            const s = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypted);
            console.log(s);

            deferred.resolve(s);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

The configuration for `params` and `cfg` are picked from the `AES` object in C#; I just wanted to make sure that the CryptoJS uses the exact same configuration as the server...

The decrypted data is always empty, so I think the deciphering failed somehow, but it does not give me any errors. I also checked, if key and IV is the same on client and server, which is the case. I guess that CryptoJS uses the given key as a passphrase and then derives new key information from it... if that would be the case, who could I prevent that... since I need to provide key and IV information?

How can I get this working?

Comment: I'd usually recommend building up complete end-to-end samples in both languages and comparing the intermediate values. (So, C# encryption and decryption routines and JS encryption and decryption routines). Once that's done you can get them to interoperate and ignore the parts you aren't planning to use. By implementing all of the routines in both languages you get to cross-check your assumptions about how both of the languages/libraries are working.

Comment: There´s a bug in the C# code that prevents the last block of encrypted data to be written to the stream; see this answer for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366842/different-encryption-results-using-c-sharp-and-cryptojs