# Different encryption results using C# and CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I encrypt some data using AES in a server application, which is written in C#. I use a predefined key (32 bytes) and IV (16 bytes), for instance...

```
Key: 81fe1681..6a451c1c
IV:  e83c..ae76
```

This is my C# code I use to encrypt the data:

```
async Task<byte[]> Encrypt(string privateKey, string pin, byte[] data)
{
    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        byte[] keyHash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{privateKey}"));
        byte[] pinHash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{pin}"));
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            byte[] key = keyHash.Slice(0, aes.Key.Length);
            byte[] iv = pinHash.Slice(0, aes.IV.Length);
            using (ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var cryptStream = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                await cryptStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                await cryptStream.FlushAsync();

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The encrypted result data looks like...

```
534c..28f5
```

Now, I want to decrypt the data in a client application using CryptoJS. I use the exact same key and IV information, but decryption seems to fail... at least the decrypted result is always empty.

So, I encrypted the data on the client (of course same key and IV) and in result the ciphered text is different; more precisely it is identical but has more data at the end...

```
534c..28f5bbd5..ac0e
```

What is this additional data at the end that I don´t get if I encrypt the data on the server?

If I decrypt the ciphered text that has been encrypted on the client, the decryption works. Just to mention it, mode and padding are default on both server and client, which is `CBC` and `Pkcs7`; keysize should be `256`. This is the code I use to decrypt the data that has been ciphered by the server:

```
let keyHash: WordArray = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(privateKey));
let key: WordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(keyHash.words.slice(0, 8), 32);

let pinHash: WordArray = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pin));
let iv: WordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(pinHash.words.slice(0, 4), 16);

let cfg: CryptoJS.lib.IBlockCipherCfg = { iv: iv };
let paramsData: CryptoJS.lib.CipherParamsData = { 
    ciphertext: cipherBuffer
};

let decrypted: WordArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(paramsData, key, cfg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the write there was a problem with the flushing of the blocks. The `FlushFinalBlock()` is distinct from the `Flush()` (or from the `FlushAsync()`). You have to do them both, or simply dispose the `CryptoStream`. This will solve the fact that the code wasn't writing the last block of data.

```
async static Task<byte[]> Encrypt(string privateKey, string pin, byte[] data)
{
    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        byte[] keyHash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{privateKey}"));
        byte[] pinHash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{pin}"));
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            byte[] key = keyHash.Slice(0, aes.Key.Length);
            byte[] iv = pinHash.Slice(0, aes.IV.Length);

            Trace.WriteLine($"Key length: { key.Length }, iv length: { iv.Length }, block mode: { aes.Mode }, padding: { aes.Padding }");

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
            {
                using (var cryptStream = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    await cryptStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The typescript code seems to be able to decrypt it.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uj58twrr/3/

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem.